# Wix Toolset Patch, Update or Upgrade: Run custom action based on already installed version (condition)

Tags: wix

I looking for a way to run a custom action based on installed version of my app.

Ex: Installed version: 2.0.1.7.

From version 2.0.1.8 there's a Windows service (instaled on every client's machines) that has become obsolete and needs to be removed by running a bat file that does this job.

So, I need to check the installed version, if it is 2.0.1.7 or older: Run this custom action. If version 2.0.1.8 or newer, I don't want to run this custom action repeatedly, because my msi's are cumulative (client can be on 2.0.1.2 and run the 2.0.1.10 directly).

**EDIT:**

After some aditional search, I found this. I'll try to use '>=' instead of '=' used on example:

> First create a RegistrySearch element:

```
<Property Id="PRODUCTVERSION">
    <RegistrySearch Id="ProductVersionSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Uninstall\[PRODUCTCODE]" Name="DisplayVersion" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

> Then use a Condition element:

```
<Condition Message="Product version 1.10.0 must be installed">
    <![CDATA[PRODUCTVERSION AND PRODUCTVERSION = "1.10.0"]]>
</Condition>
```

Source: [How to check an installed version of a product from MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453304/how-to-check-an-installed-version-of-a-product-from-msi)

**EDIT 2:**

I've got de installer version by a RegistryFind on `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[PRODUCTCODE]`

The next problem is to compare this property, because the string '2.0.1.66' isn't bigger than '2.0.1.7' and evaluates CustomAction execution to True.

**EDIT 3:**

I'm tried to use FileSearch tag with MaxVersion attribute. I can get the installed version like RegistryFind, but MaxVersion causes the same problem on string comparision.

Ex: MaxVersion="2.0.1.7" evaluates to true if file version is '2.0.1.66'.

Thanks.